# what does this do?

Tags: smarty

```
{foreach from=$s_order_items item="order_item" name="foo"}
```

What does it do? I want to know so I can tweak.

Comment: Did you [read the docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach):

> `{foreach}` is used to loop over an associative array as well a numerically-indexed array. ... Every `{foreach}` tag must be paired with a closing `{/foreach}` tag. ... Required attributes are *`from`* and *`item`*. ... The *`name`* attribute is only required when you want to access a `{foreach}` property

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach&quot;">

Comment: since im not an expert in programming and i am not familiar with smarty, i need to know what or where it comes from. Also, when i tried to tweak the code, it doesn't work by not displaying the items on page. So that's why I asked for explaination.

Comment: @Josephine OK, but I think that this is the best I can do for now. However, if you post a [dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) of `$s_order_items` (and a description of what you're trying to achieve) it may be possible to help further.